# In Excel; graph with standard deviation etc. for many measurements of many series?

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2010, charts

Let's say I have an Excel-file with 100 measurements for each N and each measurement has its own result k as follows:

```
N        k
10       32
10       38
10       25
...      ...
100      260
100      308
100      295
...      ...
...      ...
...      ...
500000   1231423
500000   1335471
```

I want to make a graph in Excel that shows each value of N as x-axis and with k' as y-axis but k' being the mean, standard deviation and median etc. of the 100 measurements for each N.

Is this possible? Thank you!

Comment: There is a range-style chart that you can use for plotting things like mean + SD or stock high/low/average.  You need to precalculate those factors, which you put into separate columns.  Then you plot those results.

Comment: Depending on how comfortable you are with stats packages you can also bring Excel data into `R` - http://www.sthda.com/english/wiki/reading-data-from-excel-files-xls-xlsx-into-r - which can then do your stats crunching for SD, etc as well as generate charts/plots/etc

Answer (score 0):

This is how I did it, rather manually.

First, use **scatter plots** with straight lines as chart type. This allows for the x-axis to be linearly distributed as compared to ordinary line charts with a series of categories. It also allows for adding a line graph of a different series with other x-values, i.e. other `N` in this case.

Secondly, for each `N` I calculated the mean `AVERAGE(range)`, the median `MEDIAN(range)`, maximum `MAX(range)`, minimum `MINIMUM(range)` and standard deviation `STDEV.P(range)` for each of the 100 measurements of N respectively. I selected the range of the first `N`, then copied my those formulas to the next row, but increased the number by a 100. E.g. `AVERAGE($D2:$D101)` for first `N` becomes `AVERAGE($D102:$D201)` for the second N and so on.

Thirdly, I added all the calculated values for each `N` into the *Select Data Source* with all the `N` as x-values and the mean, min and max as y-values. These can then be formatted to appropriate design.

Fourthly, I added standard deviation error bars for the mean value by selecting the line graph of the mean, then *Design*, *Add Chart Element*, *Error Bars* and *More Error Bars Options...*. Then in *Format Error Bars* I select *Custom* and choose my calculated standard deviation as both the positive and negative values.

Eventually, there's a better and more automatic solution if the amount of `N` would be very large, but the above worked in my case where the number och different values of `N` only where about 10 and the number of measurements per each `N` is fixed at a 100.

Answer (score 0):

Select your two columns of data, and insert a pivot table. Put N in the Rows area, and k in the Values area. The default is to display k as sum (or maybe average, I forget). But you can right click in the field in the worksheet, and select Value Field Settings, and you can select various ways to aggregate the data.

Now you can plot X = N and Y = k', where k' is some aggregation of k.